# Plotly _ Subplots :: The ‘data’ property is a tuple of trace instances

Tags: python, plotly, dashboard, subplot, plotly-dash

I am trying to create a line stacked subplots… some thing like below

[image]

multiple of these types of graphs as a subplot.

below is my code:

```
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
from plotly.tools import make_subplots

NE = pd.read_csv(“C:\py\programs\plotly\final\NE.csv”)
week_days = NE[‘date’].unique()
data1 = []
data2 = []

for day in week_days:
trace_volte_traffic = dict(type=“scatter”, x=NE[“time”], y=NE[NE[“date”] == day]
[“L.Traffic.User.VoIP.Avg”], mode=“lines+markers”, name=“volte_traffic”)
data1.append(trace_volte_traffic)

for day in week_days:
trace_PS_Traffic = dict(type=“scatter”, x=NE[“time”], y=NE[NE[“date”] == day]
[“LTE Traffic (DL+UL) - GB”], mode=“lines+markers”, name=“PS_traffic”)
data2.append(trace_PS_Traffic)

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2,
horizontal_spacing=0.1,
vertical_spacing=0.1,
subplot_titles=[‘Volte Traffic’, ‘PS Traffic’], shared_yaxes=True)

fig.append_trace(data1, 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(data2, 1, 2)

fig[‘layout’].update(height=1000, width=1600, title=‘CS Traffic’)

pyo.plot(fig)
```

but i am getting below error

```
The ‘data’ property is a tuple of trace instances that may be specified as:
- A list or tuple of trace instances (e.g. [Scatter(…), Bar(…)])
- A list or tuple of dicts of string/value properties where:
- The ‘type’ property specifies the trace type One of: [‘area’, ‘bar’, ‘barpolar’, ‘box’, ‘candlestick’, ‘carpet’, ‘choropleth’, ‘cone’, ‘contour’, ‘contourcarpet’, ‘heatmap’, ‘heatmapgl’, ‘histogram’, ‘histogram2d’, ‘histogram2dcontour’, ‘mesh3d’, ‘ohlc’, ‘parcoords’, ‘pie’, ‘pointcloud’, ‘sankey’, ‘scatter’, ‘scatter3d’, ‘scattercarpet’, ‘scattergeo’, ‘scattergl’, ‘scattermapbox’, ‘scatterpolar’, ‘scatterpolargl’, ‘scatterternary’, ‘splom’, ‘streamtube’, ‘surface’, ‘table’, ‘violin’]

    - All remaining properties are passed to the constructor of
      the specified trace type

    (e.g. [{'type': 'scatter', ...}, {'type': 'bar, ...}])
```

I am new to programming, so really thankful for your patience :).

Answer (score 0):

Please, look at [this](https://plot.ly/python/subplots/#simple-subplot) example from plotly docs. As I think, you made a mistake here:

```
data1.append(trace_volte_traffic)
```

and here:

```
fig.append_trace(data1, 1, 1)
```

You don't need to create a list `data1` or `data2`. Just assign your traces (`trace_volte_traffic` and `trace_PS_Traffic`) directly to `fig`:

```
fig.append_trace(trace_volte_traffic, 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace_PS_Traffic, 1, 2)
```

Hope it helps